# For $f$ analytic on $D_1(0)$, $|f(z)| \ge 1$ on $\partial D_1(0)$, and $f(D_1(0)) \cap D_1(0) \neq \emptyset$, show $f(D_1(0)) \supseteq D_1(0)$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\Omega \subset \mathbb{C}$ be open and containing the closed unit disc $\overline{D_1(0)}$. Let $f : \Omega \to \mathbb{C}$ be analytic with $|f(z)| \ge 1$ for $|z| = 1$. Furthermore, assume that there is some $z_0 \in D_1(0)$ so that $|f(z_0)| < 1$. Prove that $f(\Omega) \supseteq D_1(0)$.

I think that I may have come up with a proof of this result. I am hoping to have someone critique my argument, and perhaps point out an easier method of attack.

Let's restrict $f$ to $\overline{D_1(0)}$. Now, say there there is some $w \in D_1(0)$ such that $w \notin f(D_1(0))$. Then $f(z) - w$ is nonvanishing on $D_1(0)$, and continuous up to $\partial D_1(0)$. The minimum principle then says that

$$|f(z_0)| \ge |f(z_0) - w_0| \ge \min_{z \in \overline{D_1(0)}}|f(z) - w| = \min_{z \in \partial D_1(0)}|f(z) - w| \ge \min _{z \in \partial D_1(0)}||f(z)| - |w||=\min _{z \in \partial D_1(0)}(|f(z)| - |w|) \ge 1 - |w|. $$

Rearranging the inequality, we see  $|w| \ge 1 - |f(z_0)|$. So, if we set $r = 1 - |f(z_0)|$ ($0< r \le 1$), we see that the whole disk $D_r(0)$ lies in the image $f(D_1(0))$.

But now we can repeat the argument we gave above, replacing $f(z_0)$ with $0$ (since we now know that $0$ lies in $f(D_1(0))$. And then we will use the inequality again to conclude that $|w| \ge 1$. This completes the proof.

Am I on the right track or have I gotten off base somewhere? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where do you get $\lvert f(z_0)\rvert \geqslant \lvert f(z_0) - w\rvert$ from? (By the way, you get $0 \in f(\mathbb{D})$ directly from the minimum principle.)

Comment: @DanielFischer - You're right! That is a mistake. That can be replaced by $|f(z_0)| + |w| \ge |f(z_0) - w|$. But then the inequality is not so nice. Wonder what I can do to fix this.

Comment: Easier method of attack is of course subjective, but: you know $f$ is not constant. Hence $\mathbb{D}\cap f(\mathbb{D})$ is a nonempty open set. Suppose $\mathbb{D} \not\subset f(\mathbb{D})$. Then $\partial f(\mathbb{D})\cap\mathbb{D} \neq \varnothing$. And that leads to a contradiction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument works fine for $w=0$ (it's just an application of the minimum principle, as Daniel Fischer noted). Let's spell it out from the basic maximum principle:

> If $f$ omits $0$, then $1/f$ is holomorphic, hence bounded by $1$ in $\mathbb D$ by the maximum principle. This contradicts the assumption that $|f|<1$ somewhere in $\mathbb D$.

In the above form, the argument generalizes to other points of the unit disk by replacing $1/f$ with a more general Möbius map that turns the unit disk inside out. Namely:

> If $f$ omits $w_0\in \mathbb D$, then $g(z)=\dfrac{1-\overline{w_0} f(z)}{f(z)-w_0}$ is holomorphic, hence bounded by $1$ in $\mathbb D$ by the maximum principle. This contradicts the assumption that $|f|<1$ somewhere in $\mathbb D$ (because $|f|<1$ iff $|g|>1$).